# T-SQL Query Returning Items It Shouldn't Be

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Here's the scenario.  The column in question is called 'datein' and it's type is 'datetime'.  I have three rows with the value of '2009-10-01 00:00:00.000' for 'datein'.  Why does this query return the aforementioned rows?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_call AS tc
WHERE   tc.datein >= '2009-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        AND tc.datein <= '2009-09-30 23:59:59.999'
```

Using

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_call AS tc
WHERE   tc.datein BETWEEN '2009-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        AND '2009-09-30 23:59:59.999'
```

returns the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the lack of precision in the thousandths of a second value.  Try ".997" instead.

[MSDN DateTime documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(SQL.80).aspx)

Run this and you'll see:

```
declare @dt datetime

select @dt = '2009-09-30 23:59:59.999'
select @dt
```

Comment: @GregD: it's the same lack of resolution.  The DateTime time is only good for every 3 or 4 milliseconds.

Comment: Awesome.  I've marked your answer as the correct one.  Also, thanks a lot for the link.

@Joel Thanks for the additional information.

Comment: @Austin  Disregard my comment (that I've since deleted).  I was casting it to smalldatetime instead of datetime.

Comment: SQL Server 2008's DATETIME2 date type will be accurate to 100ns of precision, so you wouldn't have this problem with DATETIME2

Answer (score 3):

The [DATETIME accuracy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) is 0.00333 seconds. So you need to go to '2009-09-30 23:59:59.998' so it doesn't round up to Oct 1st.

For example:

```
select '2009-09-30 23:59:59.994', 
  cast('2009-09-30 23:59:59.994' as datetime)
union all select '2009-09-30 23:59:59.995', 
  cast('2009-09-30 23:59:59.995' as datetime)
union all select '2009-09-30 23:59:59.996', 
  cast('2009-09-30 23:59:59.996' as datetime)
union all select '2009-09-30 23:59:59.997', 
  cast('2009-09-30 23:59:59.997' as datetime)
union all select '2009-09-30 23:59:59.998', 
  cast('2009-09-30 23:59:59.998' as datetime)
union all select '2009-09-30 23:59:59.999', 
  cast('2009-09-30 23:59:59.999' as datetime)
```

returns:

```
2009-09-30 23:59:59.994 2009-09-30 23:59:59.993
2009-09-30 23:59:59.995 2009-09-30 23:59:59.997
2009-09-30 23:59:59.996 2009-09-30 23:59:59.997
2009-09-30 23:59:59.997 2009-09-30 23:59:59.997
2009-09-30 23:59:59.998 2009-09-30 23:59:59.997
2009-09-30 23:59:59.999 2009-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the column type? If it is a datetime, try casting the values you're comparing with to a datetime as well; if it is a string (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar) what collation etc. are you using for the column?

Comment: Column type is 'datetime'.  I'll add that to the op

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

> Date and time data from January 1,
>   1753 through December 31, 9999, to an
>   accuracy of one three-hundredth of a
>   second (equivalent to 3.33
>   milliseconds or 0.00333 seconds).
>   Values are rounded to increments of
>   .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown
>   in the table.

From the given example in that page, you must end your query with .997 to obtain the results that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The safe way to write these queries is as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_call AS tc
WHERE   tc.datein >= '2009-09-30T00:00:00.000'
        AND tc.datein < '2009-10-01T00:00:00.000''
```