# Why CAST('20140904 23:59:59.999' AS datetime) equals '2014-09-05 00:00:00.000'?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting, sql-server-2014

Try it for yourself, maybe it is somehow related to my environment:

**The query:**

```
SELECT CAST('20140904 23:59:59.999' AS datetime)
```

**The result:**

```
2014-09-05 00:00:00.000
```

Please explain this phenomenon.

**UPDATE**: Alex mentioned that datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds. The question is why?

Comment: There is already an answer for this ... take a look here .....
[here is an explanaition ...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506446/t-sql-query-returning-items-it-shouldnt-be

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds`

I think you should use

```
SELECT CAST('20140904 23:59:59.997' AS datetime)
```

This returns:

```
 2014-09-04 23:59:59.997
```

You can find more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

This is the accuracy of datetime function in SQL.

You could probably use datetime2 if you are using a newer version of MSSQL as the accuracy for that is 100 nanosecs.

Datetime2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Comment: The question is why?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov Because the `datetime` type has a finite precision and is not stored as a decimal number? :) Note that `datetime2` has a much bigger precision, for example.

Comment: @AnarKhalilov this is no doubt related to the inaccuracy of floating point values. According to [this page](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/sql/), the SQL standard prescribes to use IEEE754 double precision internally.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143259/1313143. Especially the comment on the answer!!!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I assume this constraint must have been causing bugs in many applications. I mean isn't it a very basic thing?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov I don't think accurate milliseconds are often needed in business software. Scientific software will probably not store them in a SQL database for reasons like this.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Many financial and banking software use SQL Server. Is Oracle the same in this regard?

Comment: While the inaccuracy in representation is understandable, all of the world rounds the result to nearest (or nearest lower) legal value, meaning in any sane system `20140904 23:59:59.999` would be rounded to `20140904 23:59:59.997`. The fact that if you're 2ms off from nearest legal value your result can be rounded by up to 86400000 milliseconds down is some kind of sick aberration.

Comment: @SF what do you mean? 20140905 00:00:00.000 *IS* the closest legal value to 20140904 23:59:59.999 with just a 1 ms difference.

Comment: @Peteris: Ooops. Didn't notice the day change.

Answer (score 3):

The increments are part of the API spec: See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007
>   seconds, as shown in the following table.

I found [this link](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/) which has at the end a better explanation. Quote:

> Actually, SQL Server does store there the clock-ticks since midnight.
>   Each clock-tick is equivalent to 3.33 milliseconds. That’s also the
>   reason why the DATETIME datatype has an accuracy of one
>   three-hundredth of a second.

DATETIME is 2 x 4 bytes (date + time). The time part is stored as number of ticks since midnight. Each tick is 3.33 ms

If you need more precision, take a look at [DATETIME2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) type. DATETIME2 Accuracy is 100ns.

Comment: Apparantly DATETIME2 is also ISO 8601 compliant, which might be useful in some scenarios.